# Сложение строк в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

есть вот такой код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400+200+100')
root.title("Калькулятор формул")

bttn_list = [
    "плотность", "масса", "oбьём", 
    "масса", "плoтность", "обьём",
    "обьём", "мaсса", "плотнoсть",

    "очистить"
    ]
r = 1
c = 0

for i in bttn_list:
    rel = ""
    ttk.Button(root, text = i).grid(row = r, column = c)
    c += 1
    if c > 4:
        c = 0
        r += 1




root.mainloop()
```

каким образом можно выполнять сложение строк (вроде плотность,масса и т.п)?

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите получить? В текущем виде вопроса ответом будет `"плотность" + "масса"`

Comment: масса = плотность * обьём, плотность = масса / обьём,обьём = масса / плотность

Comment: Добавляете поля ввода (Entry), добавляете обработчик нажатия на кнопку, в обработчике получаете значения этих полей, приводите к float, выполняете нужные действия, потом каким-то образом выводите (например, еще в одно текстовое поле).